# Any intrinsic differences between CPU conflict miss and GPU bank conflict?

Tags: gpu, conflict, bank

I am wondering whether anyone can explain to me what the intrinsic differences between CPU main memory conflict miss and GPU shared memory bank conflict. I feel that they are quite similar, as for the CPU conflict miss, the main memory addresess are mapped to the sets in the shared memory, and for the GPU banck conflict, the shared memory addresses are mapped to different banks. So, I feel that they are similar, but I may be likely to be wrong. Thanks for anyone who can provide some help!

I tried search online and understand the difference but could not figure out, so I am here to ask. Thanks!